# What is this "missing security cable"?

Tags: car-rack, installation

I recently purchased a Bell Overpass 200. On the outside of the box it says, "Warning: User must secure bicycles to carrier with additional security cable, not included. See the enclosed owners manual for proper installation and use of your bike carrier." Four rubber straps are included, though not mentioned on the box. There is no owners manual included, just the setup and takedown instructions.

*edit*  This is a car boot-mounted bike carrier

[image]

Comment: If i had to guess they're suggesting you lock your bike to the rack while in use so it doesn't get stolen. By saying that they are denying liability.

Comment: Sounds like either parts are missing or they've substituted the four rubber straps instead.  Consider contacting your supplier if you think parts are missing.

Comment: It sounds like they're simply talking about locking the bikes to the carrier.  Though they could mean a "safety cable", intended to keep the bike from falling off entirely if the other fasteners fail.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your four rubber straps are to hold the bikes together more tightly unless they're used to clamp the frame to the carrier.

The missing security strap is an anti-theft cable. Robberies from the backs of vehicles seem to be on an increase and any deterrent you can put in place to prevent theft is worthwhile.

In this case, the manufacturer is deferring the anti-theft security over to you so they are not liable if your bikes get stolen f I'm the rack.

When you're mounting your bikes, it's worth using some old rags or similar to help prevent rubbing and scratching in-transit too.

Answer (score 0):

Additional cable, to tie the bikes, to hold them better. It's better to do this, while if you don't probably nothing special will happen.
Typically I like to tie the front wheels, to prevent their movement during the journey, and keep the handles from scratches.

Comment: In a major accident the plastic clips are not strong enough to hold the  bikes on the rack.  A strap stops them flying off - in theory.

Comment: @mattnz, if the rack doesn't fold or break, and if its mounting straps hold (presumably hence "in theory"). When I  used a car rear rack I locked the bikes to a roof rail with a long adjustable cable lock for security plus attachment independent of the rack.